Move Amplify Gen2 Next.js App to subfolder in repo
I'm restructuring a bit with the nextjs sample app for amplify (https://github.com/aws-samples/amplify-next-template), as when we run this want to have it in at least one subfolder deeper
Been looking, and trying, with the monorepo setup but it just fails to run it in amplify after deploy
Is it possible instead to modify the "one app" amplify build config to just account for a subfolder?
